# PHP: why is strtotime() returning "NOW()"?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I'm calling `strtotime()` on a formatted datetime string and for some reason it always returns `NOW()`...

If my formatted datetime string (stored in the `last_seen` attribute) is: `2013-06-13 07:13:04`

and I write the following code:

```
echo $user->last_seen;
echo date('F j, Y', strtotime($user->last_seen));
```

The output I get is:

```
NOW() January 1, 1970
```

What on earth is going wrong here??? This is definitely not the expected result. The string is stored in a MySQL database, if that makes any difference.

**Edit:** by request, the code used to create the attribute in the database is:

```
$user->last_seen = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$user->save;
```

**Edit 2:** by request, the code used to pull the users table, with the user we want, is:

```
$user = User::find($user_id);
```

(not very helpful, lol).

**Edit 3:** if I `var_dump($user->last_seen)` the result is:

```
object(Laravel\Database\Expression)#40 (1) { ["value":protected]=> string(5) "NOW()" }
```

**Edit 4:** If I echo `var_dump(strtotime($user->last_seen))` the result is:

```
bool(false)
```

**Edit 5:** this problem was a result of me being an idiot, but some fine debugging was done by everyone who posted. Read the answers if you are interested.

Comment: Where do you get the object `$user` from? What does the code look like that is responsible to set is its field `last_seen`?

Comment: The `$user` object is pulled from the database using an object relational mapper (ORM) in a MVC framework. I'll edit the post with the code used to set it.

Comment: Apparently you have stored the string 'NOW()' in the database instead of a date, and you get back that string from $user->last_seen

Comment: @nos When I check the database, the weird thing is it shows the correct string, not `NOW()`. The attribute is a `datetime` if that matters.

Comment: Can you post the code on how to fetch the rows in a table, let's say, users table?

Comment: Sure @WindShear I'll edit the original post.

Comment: Can you do a var_dump($user->last_seen) and post the result? It's most likely going wrong somewhere in the ORM layer responsible for setting the last_seen attribute on the entity object.

Comment: Doing a var_dump of `$user->last_seen` right now, will update the main post.

Comment: Var dump is there.. it looks like a 5 character string to me?

Comment: What is ` $user->last_seen`?  echo that out and I think you'll find it is Now()

Comment: There's your problem.

Comment: Okay... this might be dumb but now do I make it a string corresponding to the right time, instead of `NOW()`? That's the problem... :/ eek.

Comment: Check update 4, that might help us get to the end of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all You check the return value of `strtotime($user->last_seen)`

If `strtotime($user->last_seen)` returns `false` then `$user->last_seen` may be empty or not a valid [Date and Time Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)

```
var_dump(strtotime($user->last_seen))
```

Comment: `strtotime($user->last_seen)` returns `NOW()`, not false.

Comment: Doing the `var_dump()` now.

Comment: @wnajar did you check `var_dump(strtotime($user->last_seen))` ?

Comment: Just updated the main post, it returns `bool(false)`. This seems a lot more helpful...

Comment: @wnajar `strtotime($user->last_seen)` returns `false` that is why you should get output `January 1, 1970`

Comment: I figured it out, check the answer I just submitted and have a nice laugh. Oh dear...

Comment: `$user->last_seen` contains string `now()`. Off course `strtotime('now()')` returns false... Your problem is, as I mention in my answer, the fact that `$user->last_seen` contains string `now()`.

Comment: For the final solution, check this answer and the one I submitted, and then have a nice laugh.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely not in the select clause, but lays there where you store your data.

When you are inserting the time in the database, you are probably doing

```
insert into myTable (fieldname) values ('now()');
```

instead of

```
insert into myTable (fieldname) values (now());
```

So you need to lose the quotes there...

You are NOT storing the time in the database, but the string `now()` ...

The best thing you could actually do is change the database column type from `varchar` to `DateTime`, so even the database knows it's a DateTime. Then you avoid having to cast it back to DateTime in PHP.

Comment: That's not what I did though. The way I insert the time is: `$user->last_seen = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` And when I check the database manually.. a string is indeed stored there? I could find out what the framework does in a raw SQL statement, but then that would be a bug with the framework.

Comment: Don't know, you would have to show us a bit more code to rule that out. Though I would think the framework should be able to handle something as silly as a DateTime. ... Maybe you're telling your framework that the field is a DateTime, while in fact it's a Varchar ? I'm not familiar wirh Laravel...

Comment: I figured it out... feeling dumb. See my answer.

Comment: Also, the database column type was already a DateTime, that was fine.

Comment: When you fix your problem, and `var_dump($user->last_seen)` shows it's also a DateTime object in PHP (your framework should do this for you), you can skip using `strtotime()` and `date()` , and simply do `$user->last_seen->format('F j, Y');`

Answer (score 1):

Oh dear god.... I'm going to kick myself for this one. I did a project wide `Ctrl+F` for `last_seen` and I discovered that in my routing scheme I had this:

```
Route::filter('before', function() {
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->last_seen = DB::raw('NOW()');
        $user->save();
    }
});
```

Walks away with tail between legs...

Comment: That's pretty much what I said in my answer... But with a little twist. Just to quote: `Your problem is most likely not in the select clause, but lays there where you store your data.`

Comment: I'll give you credit for it, just add in the disclaimer at the end that it was me being dumb that caused the initial problem. Thank you all for your help, a little stupidity goes a long way!